# cron - update database if session expires

Tags: php, mysql, cron

I have got a "users" table in mysql database, in one field I keep the info if the user is online.

Everything works fine apart of:

-if some user closes the browser, his online status doesn't change to offline.

I have been told that I could do that with cron, but I don't know anything about it.

I can save the user id in his session and make the php function to update the db.

But...  I have no idea how to make the cron run that php (with the id from the session)

How easy is it to do?

Answer (score 2):

It is fairly simple. This might be in your PHP file (call it update.php).

```
<?php
    /*connect to mysql as per normal*/
    // log users off (hopefully, you're using enum here, but for an example...)
    mysql_query( 'UPDATE USERS SET STATUS = \'LOGGED_OFF\' '.
               // whose last action was more than 14400 seconds ago (4 hours)
               'WHERE (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() - TIMESTAMP(LAST_ACTION)) > 14400' ); 
?>
```

Then, open crontab:

> crontab -e

and add this line to run the tast every 15 minutes (change the number 15 to another number if you like):

> */15 * * * * /path/to/update.php

Comment: That sounds brilliant :) Thank you. Could you just help me with the "open crontab" bit please? I am complete noob if it comes to cron. How do I open the crontab?

Comment: From `$` type `crontab -e` and press enter

Comment: Thank you cwallenpoole. That is brilliant :)

Answer (score 0):

Why use cron if you can just compare user's activity timestamp with current time when requested?

I assume that status goes to offline whenever user was not active for some time. So you must be storing the time of last activity in db. So when you need to respond witb user's status, compare this time with current and return `offline` if diffeence is more than allowance.

Comment: At the moment the status go to offline if user logs out by clicking a log out button.

Comment: when you return status, check both if user is logged out or timeout has expired.

Comment: So basically, I need to run a check for every user (who has a "online" status in the db) if his timestamp is not old enough to make him offline. And I have to do it every time someone does something?

Comment: Yes. But you need it only when user status is needed and you will have to check his offline flag anyway in this situation. So we are not adding much overhead as you already query this user. With cron you will need to run it every 15 minutes, for example, but do it for entire user base and do update in addition to read. So DB will be taken serious hits every 15 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Most online systems have a 15 minute check period. You set a timestamp everytime someone does something, then if they go offline they would not update their timestamp and simply compare current timestamp to that in the db and if its more then 15 minutes, delete.

Comment: Ok, so if I understand right ... User1 logs in (updates his timestamp + check is runing for all others if expired, and if they did , their status is updated in db). User2 logs in... and so on... ?